# Error: an assume statement cannot be compiled

Tags: dafny

I am trying to read from a file a certain number of bytes at a time (if I read the whole file in one go, than this works fine). I have added the lemma (`ReadLemma` in the following code to help get rid of an modifier clause error in the while loop, but now I'm getting `Error: an assume statement cannot be compiled`. Any ideas on how to fix this issue?

```
include "Io.dfy"
lemma ReadLemma(fs: FileStream, file_offset: nat32, buffer: array?<byte>, num_bytes: int32)
    requires fs.IsOpen();
    requires fs.env.Valid();
    requires fs.env.ok.ok();
    requires fs.Name() in fs.env.files.state();
    ensures fresh(buffer);
{ 
    assume false;
}
method {:main} Main(ghost env: HostEnvironment?)
    requires env != null && env.Valid() && env.ok.ok()
    modifies env.ok
    modifies env.files
{
    var argc := HostConstants.NumCommandLineArgs(env);
    if argc != 3 {
       print "[USAGE]: mono cp.exe SrcFilename DstFilename!\n";
       return;
    }

    var src := HostConstants.GetCommandLineArg(1, env);
    var dst := HostConstants.GetCommandLineArg(2, env);
    var srcResult := FileStream.FileExists(src, env);
    var dstResult := FileStream.FileExists(dst, env);
    if !srcResult {
       print "Source File Does Not Exist!\n";
       return;
    }
    if dstResult {
       print "Destiny File Already Exist!\n";
       return;
    }

    var srcSuccess, srcFs := FileStream.Open(src, env);
    if !srcSuccess {
       print "Failed to open src file!\n";
       return;
    }
    var dstSuccess, dstFs := FileStream.Open(dst, env);
    if !dstSuccess {
       print "Failed to open dst file!\n";
       return;
    }

    var success, len: int32 := FileStream.FileLength(src, env);
    if !success {
       print "Couldn't get stream size!\n";
       return;
    }

    var BYTES_TO_READ := 256;
    var file_offset, buffer, start, srcOk, dstOk := 0, new byte[BYTES_TO_READ], 0, true, true;

    while file_offset as int + BYTES_TO_READ as int < len as int
       decreases len as int - (file_offset as int + BYTES_TO_READ as int);
       invariant srcFs.IsOpen() && srcFs.env.Valid() && srcFs.env.ok.ok()
       invariant srcFs.Name() in srcFs.env.files.state()
    {
       ReadLemma(srcFs, file_offset as nat32, buffer, BYTES_TO_READ);
       srcOk := srcFs.Read(file_offset as nat32, buffer, start, BYTES_TO_READ);
       dstOk := dstFs.Write(file_offset as nat32, buffer, start, BYTES_TO_READ);
       file_offset := file_offset + BYTES_TO_READ;
    }
}
```

The Read function is a function that reads from a file. As I said, it works fine if I read the whole content of the file. Without the lemma, I get this error `call may violate context's modifies clause`.

Comment: An `assume` statement tells the verifier to blindly accept the condition you're stating. It is useful as a temporary measure to get the verifier to focus on certain parts or paths of your program. An `assume false` is like a "TODO". As long as you have an `assume` somewhere in your program (including in a lemma), then you haven't verified your program to be correct, and the compiler is complaining about this.

Comment: The remedy is to remove the `assume` statement and prove the lemma. In your case, that will be impossible, because the lemma's postcondition promises to allocate a new `buffer` and lemmas aren't allowed to allocate state. (There ought to be a warning about this.) Probably, you want to get rid of the lemma altogether and figure out what is being modified by the loop that is not allowed to be modified by the enclosing method. I suggest you look at the `modifies` clauses of `Read` and `Write`.

Comment: Thanks, @RustanLeino!